# Plot non present numbers with pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I have a large pandas Series, which contains unique numbers from 0 to 1,000,000. The series is not complete, but lacks some numbers in this range. I want to get a rough idea of what numbers are missing, so I'm thinking I should plot the data as a line with gaps showing the missing data.

How would I accomplish that? This does not work:

```
nums = pd.Series(myNumbers)
nums.plot()
```

Answer (score 1):

The following provides a list of the missing numbers in Series `nums`. You can then plot them as needed. For your purposes adjust the `max` to 1E6.

```
max = 10   # highest number to look for in the Series
import pandas as pd
nums = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9])
missing = [n for n in xrange(int(max + 1)) if n not in nums.values]
print missing

# prints: [0, 7, 8, 10]
```

I think there are two concerns with the plotting function you wrote. First, there are one million numbers. Second, the x-axis for the plot will be indexes in the series (start at 0, going sequentially); the y-axis will be numbers that you care about (`nums.values` in the code here). Therefore, you are looking for missing y-axis values.

Answer (score -1):

I think it depends on what you mean by missing. If those are nans, then you can do something like

```
len(nums[nums.apply(numpy.isnan)])
```

if you are looking for numbers that are not present between 0-1M in the series, then do something like

```
a= set([i for i in xrange(int(1e6))])
b= set(nums.values)
print len(a-b) # or plot it as scatter.
```

Comment: `set([i for i in xrange()])` makes no sense at all. `[i for i in xrange(num)]` is identical in python 2 to `range(num)`, set can also get a generator, so `set(xrange(num))` is enough.

Comment: well, I prefer making explicit lists. like you said `set(range(num))` and `set(xrange(num))` are different and range is deprecated in 3 so I avoid using it.

Comment: First, range is not deprecated in 3, how did you get that idea? . Second, there is no point in creating a really big list and then directly convert it to a set. This is exactly what generators are for.

Comment: I meant the range in python 2 is deprecated and new range behaves like xrange in 2. Am I wrong? And let me say your point about performance is taken.

Comment: It's not deprecated. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range. And `set(xrange(num)) ` is the more efficient solution in python 2.

Comment: http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/ I quote `You may have heard of a function known as xrange(). This is a function that is present in Python 2.x, however it was renamed to range() in Python 3.x, and the original range() function was deprecated in Python 3.x.`

Comment: It was removed, not deprecated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104119/discussion-between-yurlungurrr-and-maxnoe).